# Select all the columns in a table that only contain NULL values for all the rows in snowflake

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to select all the columns in a table that only contain NULL values for all the rows?
There are around 250 columns in a table.
I had checked induvial column :

```
select * from table where
column1 is not null
--column2 is not null 

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) FROM tableName
```

Is there a other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pattern here:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(column1) = 0 THEN 'all null' END AS column1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(column1) = 0 THEN 'all null' END AS column2,
    ...
    CASE WHEN COUNT(column250) = 0 THEN 'all null' END AS column250
FROM yourTable;
```

This would report `all null` for any column all of whose values are `NULL`.  You could possibly automate this by using dynamic SQL or a stored procedure.